# Index out of range error in Swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, indexing, swift3

I know there are plenty questions about that problem in SO, but i've found nothing useful for me.

I'm doing an app able to recognize movement on the screen. But Apple gestures recognizers are too precise for my use, so I'm doing my own.

It's almost done and working.

I'd like to handle multitouch gesture (like pinch) and I need to get the direction of each finger on the screen, for this I was thinking to include each direction in an array so i'll compare them easily after. But I'm getting that error of index out of range, and I don't know where I'm wrong. I'm pretty new to swift (self learning since 1 month) so it can be obvious or even a stupid mistake...

If you could please help me on this, I'd be glad. 
Thanks !

Here is my full code :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
//@IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var StatusLabel: UILabel!

var fingers = [String?](repeating: nil, count:10)
var finger1 = [CGFloat]()
var finger2 = [CGFloat]()
var finger3 = [CGFloat]()
var finger4 = [CGFloat]()
var finger5 = [CGFloat]()
var direction: String = ""
var direction1 = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        direction = ""
        direction1 = []
        finger1 = []
        finger2 = []
        finger3 = []
        finger4 = []
        finger5 = []
        for touch in touches{
            let point = touch.location(in: self.view)
            for (index,finger)  in fingers.enumerated() {
                if finger == nil {
                    fingers[index] = String(format: "%p", touch)
                    print("finger \(index+1): x=\(point.x) , y=\(point.y)")
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
        for touch in touches {
            let point = touch.location(in: self.view)
            for (index,finger) in fingers.enumerated() {
                if let finger = finger, finger == String(format: "%p", touch) {
                    switch (index){
                    case 0 :
                        finger1 += [point.x, point.y]
                    case 1 :
                        finger2 += [point.x, point.y]
                    case 2 :
                        finger3 += [point.x, point.y]
                    case 3 :
                        finger4 += [point.x, point.y]
                    case 4 :
                        finger5 += [point.x, point.y]
                    default :
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        for touch in touches {
            for (index,finger) in fingers.enumerated() {
                if let finger = finger, finger == String(format: "%p", touch) {
                    fingers[index] = nil
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        if finger1.count != 0 {
            direction1[0] += GestureRecognizer(coordinates: finger1, index: 0)
        }
        if finger2.count != 0 {
            direction1[1] += GestureRecognizer(coordinates: finger2, index: 1)
        }
        if finger3.count != 0 {
            direction1[2] += GestureRecognizer(coordinates: finger3, index: 2)
        }
        if finger4.count != 0 {
            direction1[3] += GestureRecognizer(coordinates: finger4, index: 3)
        }
        if finger5.count != 0 {
            direction1[4] += GestureRecognizer(coordinates: finger5, index: 4)
        }

        print("1 " + direction1[0] + "2 " + direction1[1] + "3 " + direction1[2] + "4 " + direction1[3] + "5 " + direction1[4])
        StatusLabel.text = direction1[1]
    }

    func GestureRecognizer (coordinates: [CGFloat], index: Int) -> String {
        if (coordinates[0] - coordinates[coordinates.count-2]) > 100 && (coordinates[1] - coordinates[coordinates.count-1]) < (-100) {
            print("Vers la gauche et bas")
            direction1[0] = "downleft"
        }
        else if (coordinates[0] - coordinates[coordinates.count-2]) < (-100) && (coordinates[1] - coordinates[coordinates.count-1]) > 100{
            print("Vers la droite et haut")
            direction1[index] = "upright"
        }
        else if (coordinates[0] - coordinates[coordinates.count-2]) < (-100 ) && (coordinates[1] - coordinates[coordinates.count-1]) < (-100){
            print("Vers la droite et bas")
            direction1[index] = "downright"
        }
        else if (coordinates[0] - coordinates[coordinates.count-2]) > 100 &&  (coordinates[1] - coordinates[coordinates.count-1]) > 100 {
            print("Vers la gauche et haut")
            direction1[index] = "upleft"
        }
        else if (-100..<100).contains(coordinates[0] - coordinates[coordinates.count-2]) && (coordinates[1] - coordinates[coordinates.count-1]) > 100 {
            print("Swipe up")
            direction1[index] = "swipeup"
        }
        else if (-100..<100).contains(coordinates[0] - coordinates[coordinates.count-2]) && (coordinates[1] - coordinates[coordinates.count-1]) < -100 {
            print("Swipe Down")
            direction1[index] = "swipedown"
        }
        else if (coordinates[0] - coordinates[coordinates.count-2]) > 100 && (-100..<100).contains(coordinates[1] - coordinates[coordinates.count-1]){
            print("Swipe left")
            direction1[index] = "swipeleft"
        }
        else if (coordinates[0] - coordinates[coordinates.count-2]) < -100 && (-100..<100).contains(coordinates[1] - coordinates[coordinates.count-1]){
            print("Swipe right")
            direction1[index] = "swiperight"
        }
        else {
            direction1[index] = "failed"
        }
        return direction1[index]
    }
}
```

Comment: There are lot of arrays were used.please debug & check it where you are getting index out of range.

Comment: @DSDharma You're right, my bad. That's when I call the function GestureRecognizer at the line : direction1[index] = "Something" That's where I get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should recheck your `direction1` array. The error is likely to be in this line:

```
print("1 " + direction1[0] + "2 " + direction1[1] + "3 " + direction1[2] + "4 " + direction1[3] + "5 " + direction1[4])
```

You've set `direction1 = []` and then you tried to print 5 different elements in your `direction1` array.

Workaround is to initialise a fixed-size array `[String](repeating: "", count: 5)` and remove this line `direction1 = []`

Comment: In fact the error is in direction1[index] = "Something", that's where it appears. 
How can I do to get the direction of each point separatly ?

Comment: Yes it is in `direction1[index] = "Something"` if `GestureRecognizer` was called. Otherwise, it's in `touchesEnded`. Check my revised answer.

Comment: @Hawkydoky no worries.